# Why is jsp rendering when tomcat is running?

Tags: spring

I am making the screen view with vue.js and the backend api with spring.
So, when spring tomcat is run, there is no need to render the jsp file. What should I do? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem you use vue.js as front end.

So you can use spring-boot with spring-mvc to build backend api which return json data.

Or the mix or hybrid ( load vue.js in jsp template ...):

Refer: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-vue-js

Comment: welcome, when join stackoverflow, if you find answer is helpful for you, you can upvote and accept it. It will be a motive for answers.